# Wrong background color of ios Buttons with tabris?

Tags: ios, eclipse, tabris

it seems the background color of the ios buttons in tabris is incorrect. On the picture below, the winter button is on the bottom yellow. The screenshot is from the ButtonControlsDemo. Is there a way to change this color ?

[image: Screenshot from ButtonControlsDemo]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This effect is caused by the "caustic highlight color".
Here is a good explanation: http://www.mlsite.net/blog/?p=235

Right now this works as intended. I'll put this on our issues list for improvements - but I can not guarantee a fix for the 1.0 release.

Comment: Actually, I looked into it and it was an easy fix. Expect this issue to be fixed in the 1.0 release.